# ANT How to use the lexically scoped properties in Ant 1.8?

Tags: scripting, ant

I have script that dosn't work becouse property once set became unwritable

```
<target name="test" >

    <fileset id="dir1" dir="./dir1"/>
    <fileset id="dir2" dir="./dir2"/>

    <pathconvert property="path.converted" refid="dir1"/>
    <echo message="${path.converted}"/>
    <property name="path.converted" value="set this property manually"/>
    <echo>${path.converted}</echo>
    <pathconvert property="path.converted" refid="dir2"/>
    <echo message="${path.converted}"/>
</target>
```

always echoed the same result, but I want that echoes was different

I read in Apache Ant 1.8.0 release, that

> Lexically scoped local properties,
>   i.e. properties that are only defined
>   inside a target, sequential block or
>   similar environment. This is very
>   useful inside of s where a
>   macro can now define a temporary
>   property that will disappear once the
>   task has finished.

How to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution. Use [local task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html)

```
<target name="direct" depends="">

    <fileset id="dir1" dir="./dir1"/>
    <fileset id="dir2" dir="./dir2"/>

    <!--<property name="path.converted" value="0"/>-->
    <local name="path.converted"/>

    <pathconvert property="path.converted" refid="dir1"/>
    <echo message="${path.converted}"/>
    <local name="path.converted"/>
    <property name="path.converted" value="0"/>

    <echo>${path.converted}</echo>
    <local name="path.converted"/>
    <pathconvert property="path.converted" refid="dir2"/>
    <echo message="${path.converted}"/>

</target>
```

Comment: stackoverflow message: You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use different names for path.converted for the example above.
path.converted.1, path.converted.2 etc.

If you would have created a macrodef you should definitely use the **local** task to make the property local.